# Can't see wsdl document on given address

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, wcf-hosting

I am trying my first WCF service, hence this could be a silly question. I have created a WCF service with service contract as

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAutoComplete
{
    [OperationContract]
    string[] Complete(string str);
}
```

And implementation of service as below:

```
public class AutoComplete : IAutoComplete
{
    string[] IAutoComplete.Complete(string str)
    {
        DBContext context = new DBContext();
        return context.MVCDemoes.Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith(str)).Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I have hosted my service in Console Application

Here is hosting configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AutoCompleteService.AutoComplete" behaviorConfiguration="AutocompleteBehavior">
        <endpoint address="AutoComplete" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AutoCompleteService.IAutoComplete"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/YOUR_ADDRESS/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AutocompleteBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have started service but when I go to http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/YOUR_ADDRESS/AutoComplete I see blank page. No error but just a blank page. What could be the issue?

Comment: Try going to http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/YOUR_ADDRESS/mex

Comment: Still nothing, however it's been consumed perfectly